After `brew install R`, I write `~/.Rprofile`, and R do not load this file, why?
As title shown, after using brew install R(no GUI version), the R code options('repos) returns
$repos
    CRAN
"@CRAN@"

So I want to write the file ~/.Rprofile to customize the repos.
The code below is written in .Rprofile.
options("repos" = c(CRAN='https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/CRAN/'))

But It is failed, still returns $repos CRAN "@CRAN@".
Why?
It's very smooth to write like this on windows, but not work in mac.
I have no idea.
Put .Rprofile to the right path ~, but can not be loaded.
Does someone have the same problem?

Did you restart R after making the change? The Rprofile file is only loaded at startup.

It’s very hard to diagnose what might be going wrong but as a general rule you shouldn’t install R via Homebrew. It works OK, but installation via the original installer works better. Even better yet, use rig. It not only installs R properly and allows multiple versions in parallel, but also sets up a sane configuration for R.

@MrFlick. Yes, this is common sense. I not only restarted the terminal, but also restarted the Mac. Like the difference between .zshprofile and .zhsrc.

@KonradRudolph. Thank you very much, I will see the rig. Since I use a package manager conda and pixi in Python and have similar features like Juliaup, I should indeed use the r manager. That is a good idea.
